# Should I use Java 8 Streams Api to combine two Collections?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this situation where it seems that the Java 8 Streams API would be helpful, but I'm not fully sure how it could be.

From two Collections with distinct element types, I want to build a third collection whose elements are all the possible *Pairs* of elements from both collections. Basically:

The two distinct element types...

```
public class A {}
public class B {}
```

A "pair" of As and Bs.

```
public class Pair {
   private A a;
   private B b;

   public Pair(A a, B b){
     this a = a;
     this b = b;
   }
}
```

The "*combination*" made using old-style `java.util.Collection` API:

```
 public Collection<Pair> combine(Collection<A> as, Collection<B> bs){
    Collection<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList();
    foreach(A a: as){
      foreach(B b: bs){
          Pair pair = new Pair(a,b);
          pairs.add(pair);
      }
    }
    return pairs;
 }
```

The ordering in the resulting pairs collection is not important. So, every instance of Pair could be created and added to the resulting collection in parallel. How could I achieve this?

The best I could figure out by myself was to use the Streams version of `foreach`:

```
as.foreach(
  a -> {
    bs.foreach(
      b -> {
          Pair pair = new Pair(a,b);
          pairs.add(pair);
      }
  }
);
```

This example was made trivial for the sake of simplification. The class `Pair` is an example of processing two elements into a third one (that is, a `java.util.function.BiFunction`), and adding them to a `Collection` is just an example of a mutable reduction.

Is there a more elegant way to do that? Or preferable, in a more profitable way in regards to efficiency? Something like

```
BiFunction<A,B,Pair> combinator = Pair::new; //or any other function f(a,b)=c;

Stream<Pair> pairStream = 
  Streams.unknownElegantMethod(as.stream(), bs.stream(), combinator);
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but instead of `(a,b) -> {return new Pair(a,b)}; use `Pair::new`. And for the question, stream are usable once. And you Java code shows that you are using a stream more than one time (the one on `bs`).

Comment: Nice point about ``Pair:new``, I've updated the question. Second point is mistaken, as ``bs`` is a ``Collection``, and not a stream.

Comment: No, I understood. What I meant is that when you used up a stream, you can't use it anymore. So the solution can't or will never  be something like `Stream<Pair> pairStream = 
  Streams.unknownElegantMethod(as.stream(), bs.stream(), combinator);` if, and only if, you want all possible pairs of (A, B). The use of `flatMap` (as in the answer), or `foreach` (as in your code), is the only solution.

Answer (score 24):

I hope I don't have any silly typos, but basically what you can do is :

```
List<Pair> list = as
                  .stream()
                  .flatMap(a -> bs.stream().map (b -> new Pair(a,b)))
                  .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

1. First you create a `Stream<A>` from `as`.
2. For each `a` instance
   2.1 Create a `Stream<B>` of `bs`
   2.2 Map each `b` to a pair of `(a,b)`
3. Flatten all the pairs to a single Stream.
4. Finally I collected them to a List, though you can choose other collections.

Comment: typo: bs, not b, is the name of the collection of b's. SE won't let me make this useful edit :(

Comment: When compiling this, I get 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Pair>'. flatMap doesn't seem to be getting the correct type from the lambda. I fixed it with 
`List<Pair> list = as.stream().flatMap(a -> bs.stream().map (b -> new Pair(a,b)).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());`
but the fix seems kind of adhoc as it converts the stream into a collection then back to a stream again.

Comment: this is called a 'cartesian' or 'cross' join

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you could use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) `Sets.cartesianProduct()`.  This would require that your a's and b's are both Sets.  Eclipse Collections has a `Pair` type built-in, so you wouldn't need to create it.

```
public class A {}
public class B {}

public List<Pair<A, B>> combine(Set<A> as, Set<B> bs)
{
    return Sets.cartesianProduct(as, bs).toList();
}
```

If your a's and b's are not Sets, then you could use a `CollectionAdapter` `flatCollect` and `collect`, which are equivalent to `flatMap` and `map` on `Stream`.

```
public Collection<Pair<A, B>> combine(Collection<A> as, Collection<B> bs)
{
    MutableCollection<B> adaptB = CollectionAdapter.adapt(bs);
    return CollectionAdapter.adapt(as)
            .flatCollect(a -> adaptB.asLazy().collect(b -> Tuples.pair(a, b)));
}
```

Another possible option using `Stream` would be to define your own `Collector` for `cartesianProduct`.  This is more complex than the other `Stream` solution, and would only be useful if you used `cartesianProduct` a few times in your code.

```
List<Pair<A, B>> pairs = as.stream().collect(cartesianProduct(bs));

public static <T1, T2> Collector<T1, ?, List<Pair<T1, T2>>> 
    cartesianProduct(Collection<T2> other)
{
    return Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (list, a) -> list.addAll(
                other.stream().map(b -> new Pair(a, b))).collect(Collectors.toList())),
            (list1, list2) ->
            {
                list1.addAll(list2);
                return list1;
            },
            Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED
    );
}
```

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).